# "self height" of row/cell in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

So, looking at the HTML code below, my problem is that I have a CSS grid populated by elements that are administered by a CMS admin, I.e. they can add elements to this grid and set the width of each element and thus populate the grid. One of the item they can add is an "special" item, which fetches and displays an ad. The problem is that the ad is uploaded with a fixed size and aspect ratio, while the width of the grid (in the code set to 600px) is flexible depending on the site it is displayed on. The height of this element is calculated according to this ratio (displayed as 100px in the example) which means that the content is smaller than the row height.

How do I approach this? I can't programtically - as far as I can see - predict what row the ad will be displayed in (notice how "Offer 2" is after the ad code-wise but flowed before it in the grid so it's hard for me to approach this directly in the #grid CSS grid-template-rows because the admin can choose to display the ad in the first, second or seventh row, or it can be reflowed to the first row available as well.

As you can see, the ad is always full-width so it's always on a row of itself, so I would want something like "self-row-template" or something, which isn't feasible given the fact that it's an element in a cell.

Any idea how to solve this?

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 600px;
  grid-auto-rows: 120px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 10px;
}
#grid .item {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font: 1.5em bold;
  line-height: 120px;
}
#grid .item.width2 {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
#grid .item.width3 {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}
#grid .item.special {
  grid-column: auto / span 5 !important;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class='item link width2'>Link 1</div>
  <div class='item link width3'>Link 2</div>
  <div class='item offer width3'>Offer 1</div>
  <div class='item special width2'>*Special*</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 2</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 3</div>
  <div class='item link'>Link 3</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define row height, only define elements height

```css
#grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 600px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  gap: 10px;
}
#grid .item {
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  font: 1.5em bold;
  line-height: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}
#grid .item.width2 {
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
#grid .item.width3 {
  grid-column: auto / span 3;
}
#grid .item.special {
  grid-column: auto / span 5 !important;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='grid'>
  <div class='item link width2'>Link 1</div>
  <div class='item link width3'>Link 2</div>
  <div class='item offer width3'>Offer 1</div>
  <div class='item special width2'>*Special*</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 2</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 3</div>
  <div class='item link'>Link 3</div>
  <div class='item offer width2'>Offer 4</div>
</div>
```